# Drawing tools regarding

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am using TikZ to draw pictures... Here i will give one of my drawing. I thing i used here is so lengthy. So is there any simple way of drawing this?

```
\begin{document}\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[pattern color=black,pattern=dots] (0,1) rectangle (3,1.2);
\draw (1.5,1.3) node[above] {0};
\draw[fill=black] (3,1) rectangle (6,1.2);
\draw[pattern color=blue,pattern=dots] (6,1) rectangle (9,1.2);
\draw (7,1.3) node[above] {2};
\draw[pattern=dots](0,0) rectangle (1,.2);
\draw (0.5,.3) node[above]{0};
\draw[fill=black](1,0) rectangle (2,.2);
\draw[pattern=dots](2,0) rectangle (3,.2);
\draw (2.5,.2) node[above] {2};
\draw[fill=black] (3,0) rectangle (6,.2);
\draw[pattern=dots](6,0) rectangle (7,.2);
\draw (6.5,.2) node[above] {0};
\draw[fill=black](7,0) rectangle (8,.2);
\draw[pattern=dots](8,0) rectangle (9,.2);
\draw (8.5,.2) node[above] {2};
\draw[pattern=dots](0,-1) rectangle (0.3,-1.2);
\draw (0.15,-1) node[above] {0};
\draw[fill=black](0.3,-1) rectangle (0.65,-1.2);
\draw[pattern=dots](0.65,-1) rectangle (1,-1.2);
\draw (.75,-1) node[above] {2};
\draw[fill=black](1,-1) rectangle (2,-1.2);
\draw[pattern=dots](2,-1) rectangle (2.3,-1.2);
\draw (2.15,-1) node[above] {0};
\draw[fill=black](2.3,-1) rectangle (2.65,-1.2);
\draw[pattern=dots](2.65,-1) rectangle (3,-1.2);
\draw (2.75,-1) node[above] {2};
\draw[fill=black] (3,-1) rectangle (6,-1.2);
\draw[pattern=dots](6,-1) rectangle (6.3,-1.2);
\draw (6.15,-1) node[above] {0};
\draw[fill=black](6.3,-1) rectangle (6.65,-1.2);
\draw[pattern=dots](6.65,-1) rectangle (7,-1.2);
\draw (6.85,-1) node[above] {2};
\draw[fill=black](7,-1) rectangle (8,-1.2);
\draw[pattern=dots](8,-1) rectangle (8.3,-1.2);
\draw (8.15,-1) node[above] {0};
\draw[fill=black](8.3,-1) rectangle (8.65,-1.2);
\draw[pattern=dots](8.65,-1) rectangle (9,-1.2);
\draw (8.85,-1) node[above] {2};
\draw (4,-2) node { Points of the Cantor Set pass through sieves};
\end{tikzpicture}\end{center}\end{document}
```

Comment: Just two or three lines more before `\begin{document}`, showing the preamble and *voilà!* you made the document compilable, saving us from having to write anything.

Comment: @David Please post your minimal working example beginning with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that It also helps if you post a picture of what you want to do or what have you achieved so far regarding your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As there is kind of a pattern visible in the distribution of the numbers and filled squares I made excessive use of `\foreach`.

I adjusted the coordinate system, such that the full length of a bar is `9cm`, i.e. , `1 = 9cm` in this drawing. The bars are placed at `y = 1,2,3`, respectively. The bar height is `.2`. Also the pattern color is set to `black` (default) for all bars.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=9cm]
  % Squares
  \foreach \i in {1,2,3} {
    \filldraw[pattern=dots] (0,\i) rectangle (1,\i+.2);
    \filldraw (1/3,\i) rectangle (2/3,\i+.2);
  \ifnum\i<3
    \foreach \j in {1,7} {
      \filldraw (\j/9,\i) rectangle (\j/9+1/9,\i+.2);
    }
  \fi
  \ifnum\i<2
    \foreach \j in {1,7,19,25} {
      \filldraw (\j/27,1) rectangle (\j/27+1/27,1+.2);
    }
  \fi
  }
  % Nodes
  \foreach \i in {1,2,3} {
    \node[above] at (1/3^\i-1/2/3^\i,4-\i+.2) {0};
    \node[above] at (3/3^\i-1/2/3^\i,4-\i+.2) {2};
  \ifnum\i>1
    \node[above] at (7/3^\i-1/2/3^\i,4-\i+.2) {0};
    \node[above] at (9/3^\i-1/2/3^\i,4-\i+.2) {2};
  \fi
  \ifnum\i>2
    \node[above] at (19/3^\i-1/2/3^\i,1+.2) {0};
    \node[above] at (21/3^\i-1/2/3^\i,1+.2) {2};
    \node[above] at (25/3^\i-1/2/3^\i,1+.2) {0};
    \node[above] at (27/3^\i-1/2/3^\i,1+.2) {2};
  \fi
  }
  \node at (1/2,0) {Points of the Cantor Set pass through sieves};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: You should probably point out the changes you have made to the image---most notably the change of color from blue to black.

Comment: @eiterorm Is there something blue in OPs picture?

Comment: `pattern color=blue` is a possibility ;).

Comment: @cfr True. I didn't notice.

Answer (score 5):

How about a recursive `pic`?:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\tikzset{pics/.cd,
  cantor set/.style args={#1 by #2 order #3}{
    code={
      \pgfmathparse{int(#3)}\let\C=\pgfmathresult
      \draw [pattern=dots] (0,0) rectangle (#1,#2);
      \ifnum\C>0
        \fill (#1*1/3,0) rectangle (#1*2/3,#2);      
        \ifnum\C=1\relax
          \node [above] at (#1*1/6,#2) {0};
          \node [above] at (#1*5/6,#2) {2};
        \else
          \pic               {cantor set={#1/3 by #2 order #3-1}};
          \pic at (#1*2/3,0) {cantor set={#1/3 by #2 order #3-1}};
        \fi
      \fi
    }
  },
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\pic at (0,3) {cantor set={8cm by .25cm order 1}};
\pic at (0,2) {cantor set={8cm by .25cm order 2}};
\pic at (0,1) {cantor set={8cm by .25cm order 3}};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick example:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[pattern=dots] (0,1) rectangle (3,1.2);
\draw (1.5,1.3) node[above] {0};
\draw[fill] (3,1) rectangle (6,1.2);
\draw[pattern=dots,pattern color=blue] (6,1) rectangle (9,1.2);
\draw (7,1.3) node[above] {2};

\foreach \i in {0.2,-1}{
    \draw[pattern=dots] (0,\i-0.2) rectangle (9,\i);
    \draw[fill] (3,\i-0.2) rectangle (6,\i);
    \draw[fill] (1,\i-0.2) rectangle (2,\i);
    \draw[fill] (7,\i-0.2) rectangle (8,\i);
}

% Note: I assumed the one node with height 0.3 was intended to be 0.2 like the others
\foreach \j in{0,1,3,4}{
    \draw(2*\j+0.5,0.2) node[above] {\pgfmathparse{iseven(\j) ? 0 : 2}\pgfmathresult};
}

% Note: I assumed the nodes at position *.75 were intended to be placed at *.85, like on the right side
\foreach \m in {0,2,6,8}{
    \draw[fill] (\m+0.3,-1) rectangle (\m+0.65,-1.2);
    \foreach \n in {0.15,0.85}{
        \draw(\m+\n,-1) node[above] {\pgfmathparse{\n==0.15 ? 0 : 2}\pgfmathresult};
    }
}

\draw (4,-2) node { Points of the Cantor Set pass through sieves};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This should be shorter than your example, and in addition have better structure. I have left the topmost line largely unchanged, as you have changed the color of the pattern and placed the number 2 rather arbitrarily.

There are many different ways of simplifying the code, but they all come down to one thing: describing patterns (not the `tikz` decoration, of course, but rather what's going on in the image).

A few notes on the code:

- Instead of drawing many small dotted rectangles, you can draw a single long one, and draw the black rectangles on top.
- Black is the default color. Unless you have specified another color to be the default one, there is no need to specify black as the fill color.
- There is a certain amount of repetition in your image. Thus the code can be reduced by using a few loops and a bit of math.

The code can be further simplified, but I'll leave that to you.

For more information about the commands, please refer to [the `tikz` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf). The `\foreach` command is described in chapter 83 (pp. 909--913) and a number of math expressions can be found in chapter 90 (pp. 933--944). The functions and operators I've used in the node expressions can be found on pages 934, 939 and 942.