# Diagram of a variation of the middle third Cantor set

Tags: math-mode, diagrams, amsmath

I would like to construct a diagram which is a variation of the middle third Cantor set as described by:

Suppose we start off with the unit interval `$[0,1]$`; let us call it `$A_0$`. Next, remove the segment `$(1/4,3/4)$` and then repeat the process on the two intervals `$[0,1,4]$` and `$[3/4,1]$` which make up `$A_1$`. In doing so we obtain `$A_2=[0,1]\setminus \{ (1/16,3/16)\cup(13/16,15/16) \}$`. We define the set `$A$` by repeating process ad infinitum and so `$A= \cap_{k=0}^{\infty} A_k$`.

I would like this diagram to look something like this (my middle third Cantor diagram):

[image: wanted]

I do not know nothing anything about constructing these diagrams.

Comment: I dont know why the $$'s arent creating math-like text.

Comment: We do not have mathjax on this site, if you want to show some tex output, upload an image.

Comment: Did you look for Cantor here?http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31999/drawing-cantor-set, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/200545/drawing-tools-regarding/200604#200604, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/136907/recursive-drawing-command-flow